# Find and fill in input field by data attribute

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, capybara

I want to find elements by a "test" data attribute and fill them in like the following:

```
When(/^I sign in with valid credentials$/) do
  email = page.find("data-test='email'")
  password = page.find("data-test='password'")
  fill_in email, with: @user.email
  fill_in password, with: @user.password
  submit = page.find("[data-test='submit']")
  submit.click
end
```

The button works fine, but the inputs throw the following error:

```
Unable to find field #<Capybara::Element tag="input"> (Capybara::ElementNotFound)
```

Is there a way to do this in capybara? Thanks in advance for the help.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`fill_in` method accepts element's id, name or label text, so it might not work with the result the find method returns. In your case try the `set` method:

```
find("input[data-test='email']").set(@user.email)
```

Comment: `fill_in` accepts element's id, name or label text, so it might not work with the result the `find` method returns. In your case try the `set` method: `find("input[data-test='email']").set(@user.email)`